# Why space doesn't as same as enter when I use scanf?

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

I have this code:

```
int a, b;
scanf("%d", &a);
scanf("%d", &b);

printf("%d", a + b);
```

when I have this input the program works fine:

```
1<enter>2<enter>
```

and returns `3` (as expected!)

but when I try to enter my inputs using `<space>` key:

```
1<space>2<space>
```

nothing happens and I have to press `<enter>` after all to make my program to go to next line.

So what's the problem? why space works sometime and wont works some other times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stdin` is often line-buffered, not immediate.

Thus, prior to pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, your program does not get the input at all.

Comment: Because the enter sends all the input up to and including the enter to the program. As a test, try printing something between the two `scanf`-calls. BTW: You should test their return-values anyway.